# neo4j cypher query- cpu usage profiler

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I see the cpu getting close to 100% for lots of cypher queries, which being run of a strong machine (16 cores, 110 GB RAM, SSD etc for 10GB neo4j database)

is there a way to profile a cypher query for other aspects than db hits? for example: cpu usage of each statement, locks etc

**server config:**

neo4j-wrapper:

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=31768
wrapper.java.maxmemory=31768
```

neo4j.properties:

```
  dbms.pagecache.memory=70g
```

java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -e '(Initial\|Max)HeapSize'

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx32g -Xms32g
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 34359738368                         {product}
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 34359738368                         {product}
```

jstack output:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ktvflamjqoz9dnu/sudo_jstack%20_13453?dl=0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kinds of queries are you running? Could you produce a threaddump of your neo4j server and share it? (kill -3 <pid> or jstack <pid>)

Comment: Would you be able to share `vmstat 3` or some metrics like `iotop` ?

Comment: thanks Michael, i've added partially. i will add dump as well. you mean kill -3 to the top process of neo4j, right..?

Comment: Yup, ok so at least no io-bound / IO - wait.

Comment: Then it is mostly either optimizing the queries or if it is the most critical use-case of the system consider using Neo4j's embedded APIs. Can we look at your queries again, perhaps in a separate post with PROFILE output?

Comment: added jstack output. i suspect locks btw. is there an option to query with isolation level "uncommitted"?

Comment: @michael-hunger can i send it personally please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to profile specific queries for CPU usage, but have you configured Neo4j to allow it to use more memory?  How much memory is it using?

Also, is this in production with a number of queries hitting the database, or are you making queries yourself with the web console?  If the latter, sometimes a query will continue running even if you've cancelled it.  You can help alleviate that by setting a [query timeout](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/17/neo4j-setting-query-timeout/) (say for 60 seconds).

Comment: thanks,
i've edited the original post. 
these are queries that a "node.js semaphore" runs - 10 at a time